# Mostrar imagenes mediante socket (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, socket

Tengo un proyecto personal, es una sala de chat, la estoy haciendo a modo 'entrenamiento' en el mundo de los sockets.
El chat funciona correctamente, pero se me ocurrió poder hacer que el user comparta imagenes.
Para ello, existe un boton (html), que permite seleccionar una imagen, despues la paso a base64 y la paso como mensaje.
El problema esta en que el socket no lo llega a recibir. El problema no es la comunicacion, ya que el chat funciona, es el tamaño del buffer.
He probado a subirlo a 10MB, pero sin cambios.
**Codigo**

> webSocket.php

Me salto la parte del handshaking para no hacerlo mas grande...

```
        //Create TCP/IP sream socket
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        //reuseable port
        socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
        //bind socket to specified host
        socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
        //listen to port
        socket_listen($socket);
        //create & add listning socket to the list
        $clients = array($socket);
        //start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
        while (true) {
            //manage multipal connections
            $changed = $clients;
            //returns the socket resources in $changed array
            socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

            //check for new socket
            if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
                //CUANDO CONECTA SALTA AQUI
                $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
                $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

                $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024*1024*5); //aqui es el tamaño en bytes del socket
                perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

                socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
                $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>'Nuevo Conectado!'))); //prepare json data
                $ahora = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
                echo "$ahora --> Conexion aceptada, handshake realizado con exito...\n";
                send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

                //make room for new socket
                $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
                unset($changed[$found_socket]);
            }
}
```

> index.html

```
txt = $("#texto").val()
        var msg = {
            'id': id,
            'user': user,
            'type': 'mensaje',
            'message': txt
        };
        console.log(txt);
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

En index.html txt ya esta en Base64, contiene la imagen y esta en formato correcto.

Si lo pruebo con una imagen de 5Kb funciona.

**Edito, pruebas dia 1**
Al ver que imagenes de menos de 10Kb si se muestran, decidi hacer paquetes del Base64 que no fueran superiores a los 10Kb, y pasarlo tantas veces como fuera necesario.
A la funcion la llame `getBase64()`, funciona correctamente, pero por desgracia el `socket` hace lo mismo, lee el primer paquete y se queda pillado.
Aqui pongo el codigo para que se vea, y por si le sirve a alguien.

```
function getBase64(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            console.log(reader.result);
            var txt = reader.result;

            txt = txt.split(";")[1];

            var largoTexto = txt.length;
            var limite = 10*1024; //10Kb
            var veces =parseInt((largoTexto/limite)+1);

            var arrayTemp = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < veces; i++) {
                var part = txt.substring(limite*i, limite*(i+1));
                arrayTemp.push(part);
                console.info(i, " VEZ");
                var msg = {
                    'id': id,
                    'user': user,
                    'type': 'imagen',
                    'message': 'imagen',
                    'data': part

                };
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));    

            }
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
    }
```

Si falta alguna información pedirla.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resuelto, el problema era la configuración del PHP.
En `php.ini` poner:

```
upload_max_filesize 4M
```

O directamente en el fichero `PHP`

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '4M');
```

Así podemos pasar tamaños superiores a 2 Mb que es el standar.

Gracias a todos!